# Custom OverviewMap in OpenLayers - missing className parameter

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

in [example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overviewmap-custom.html) on Openlayers website regarding customizing overview maps one of parameter is "className". In example "className" parameter belong to **ol.control.OverviewMap** object but [object in documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.control.OverviewMap.html) no mention about that parameter and i can't find any information about it. Could you explain me when that parameter removed from OverviewMap object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code, it is still being used. Maybe it's just an inadvertent omission from the docs.

https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/control/overviewmap.js

```
var className = options.className !== undefined ? options.className : 'ol-overviewmap';
```

Comment: 'options' comes from 'opt_options'. 'opt_options' is type of olx.control.OverviewMapOptions but OverviewMapOptions doesn`t have field className. It means that I can put className to OverviewMap.

Comment: It seems to work fine, here is a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xdbvgL90/   Are you using the closure compiler? Maybe inside closure type safety restrictions prevent you from doing that, but outside of closure you can put any parameter on the opt_options object you want without error, including "className". They'd just be ignored. But OverviewMap is specifically handling className, despite what the documentation and typedef indicate. Hope that helps.

Comment: Jeff you are right. My problem was cause by TypeScript. I'm beginner in JS and some solution are little confuse for me.